# C# Class Inheritance Pattern Multiple Classes

Tags: c#, .net, oop, design-patterns

I have two abstract classes

```
public abstract class PluginBase
{
    protected SettingBase LocalSettings { get; set; }
}

public abstract class SettingBase
{
}
```

I am then creating a new class using PluginBase, and along with it I create a class using SettingBase

```
public class MyPlugin : PluginBase
{

}

public class MySettings : SettingBase
{
    public string MyValue;
}
```

I then load an instance of "MySettings", into the "LocalSettings" property.

Within MyPlugin I would then like to access the "MyValue" property of the "LocalSettings" property.  I know I can access it like this;

```
((MySettings)LocalSettings).MyValue;
```

But I am looking for a nicer way to do this, preferably without the need to constantly reference the new type every time, something like this;

```
MyLocalSettings.MyValue
```

I would ideally like to avoid referencing properties with any string based methods.

Comment: As a bizarre solution you could use `dynamic` property for LocalSettings :)

Comment: What does this mean? "I have two abstract classes that contain some base methods?" in this context every word means something, so I recommend being more literal. Are the methods virtual, abstract, or neither?

Comment: @ScottHannen The classes are fairly large, and contain a mixture of lots of things(Statics, abstracts, constant, etc), and they also inherit from another set of classes as well.  I thought it best not to muddy the waters as it shouldn't impact a design pattern.  Or would you disagree?

Comment: I just had a moment of disconnect when I started reading the question. This sort of question is all about the details, so it's a good idea to use very precise language. "I have two abstract classes that contain some methods," or "I have two abstract classes that contain some abstract | virtual methods." The addition of the word "base" is confusing if it doesn't actually mean something. (I'm almost splitting hairs.)

Comment: Not at all, you're totally right, even asking questions like this is full of pitfalls.  I'll update to clarify :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could generics work for you maybe?

```
public abstract class PluginBase
{
    // move it to the generic base class
    // protected SettingBase LocalSettings { get; set; }
}

public abstract class PluginBase<TSettings> : PluginBase where TSettings : SettingBase
{
    protected TSettings LocalSettings { get; set; }
}

public abstract class SettingBase
{
}

public class MyPlugin : PluginBase<MySettings>
{
    public void DoIt()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this.LocalSettings.MyValue);
    }
}

public class MySettings : SettingBase
{
    public string MyValue;
}
```

Comment: I think generics are necessary. The only way to know that the settings class is a specific type, and therefore has a given property, is to declare it as that type. Any solution that results in assumptions or guesses about an object's type is a bad solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just make `SettingsBase` actually contract anything than just emptiness:

```
public abstract class SettingBase
{
    public abstract object GetSettingValue( string settingName );
}
```

This imposes an obligation for the implementor

```
public class MySettings : SettingBase
{
    public override object GetSettingValue( string settingName )
    {
        switch (settingName) 
        {
            case "MySetting": ...
```

but gives a Chance to the client to use the obligation

```
this.LocalSettings.GetSettingValue( "MySetting" );
```

without any cast to specific implementation type.

Comment: I like that, and I actually use a similar solution elsewhere with an inherited base class that provides that functionality.  However in this case, I want it strongly typed, not string based.  Will update question to reflect this.

Comment: You can make consts out of strings so that the very same const is used both at the client and in the provider. That would be kind of "strongly" typed.